# How to separate row from comma in a field when create a mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to `create view` in mysql.

My select query is working fine to correct output. Here is my code ::

```
SELECT id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(colors, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) color
FROM colors
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(colors, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(colors)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  id,
  n.digit;
```

When i put it a view it faced some issue, error message is :: `View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause`

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(colors, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) color
FROM colors
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(colors, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(colors)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  id,
  n.digit;
```

Please help me about this error.

Comment: If you really want to do this,  create a view for the subquery and join that view. Also why not do a search on the error mesage, this has been answered a lot.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html says:

> Before MySQL 5.7.7, subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-7.html says:

> Previously, view definitions were not permitted to contain derived tables (subqueries) in the FROM clause. This restriction has now been lifted.
>
> Previously, derived tables (subqueries) or views in the FROM clause could not be merged into the outer query if they contained subqueries in the SELECT list. Instead, they were processed using materialization. This restriction has now been lifted so that queries previously executed using materialization can be executed more quickly using merging.

So upgrade to MySQL 5.7.7 or later.